# Netbeans error in c :make.exe error :build/Debug/MinGW-Windows/my-project-error.o

Tags: c, netbeans

i am writing the following code in my netbeans sdk :

```
int main() {
printf("Hello World");
return 0;
}
```

and it gives me the following error :

```
make.exe[2]: *** [build/Debug/MinGW-Windows/fourier-transform.o] Error 1
make.exe[2]: Leaving directory 
`/c/Users/As-/Documents/NetBeansProjects/CppApplication_1'
make.exe[1]: *** [.build-conf] Error 2
make.exe[1]: Leaving directory 
`/c/Users/As-/Documents/NetBeansProjects/CppApplication_1'
make.exe": *** [.build-impl] Error 2

 BUILD FAILED (exit value 2, total time: 59s)
```

Any help in why is this error ?

Comment: This cannot be the complete error message.

Comment: Have you included required files? For example stdio.h?

Comment: Yes thank you i have added the include file as in this print screen:
    #include<stdio.h>
    
    int main() {
    printf("c plus programming");
    return 0;
    }

Comment: Yes thank you i have added the include file as in this print screen:
    #include<stdio.h>
    
    int main() {
    printf("c plus programming");
    return 0;
    }

but in running the code, i am receiving a dialogue box of : Resolve missing 
native build tools asking about  :
QMake Command parameter.

What to write ?

Comment: but when i run it as an application not project i am reciveing the error despite of the header included: as follows:

Comment: cd 'C:\Users\Asus\Documents\NetBeansProjects\CppApplication_1'
C:\MinGW\msys\1.0\bin\make.exe -f Makefile CONF=Debug
"/C/MinGW/msys/1.0/bin/make.exe" -f nbproject/Makefile-Debug.mk QMAKE=

Comment: SUBPROJECTS= .build-conf
make.exe[1]: Entering directory `/c/Users/Asus/Documents/NetBeansProjects/CppApplication_1'
nbproject/Makefile-Debug.mk:98: warning: overriding commands for target `build/Debug/MinGW-Windows/newmain.o'
nbproject/Makefile-Debug.mk:93: warning: ignoring old commands for target `build/Debug/MinGW-Windows/newmain.o'
"/C/MinGW/msys/1.0/bin/make.exe"  -f nbproject/Makefile-Debug.mk dist/Debug/MinGW-Windows/cppapplication_1.exe

Comment: make.exe[2]: Entering directory 
`/c/Users/Asus/Documents/NetBeansProjects/CppApplication_1'
nbproject/Makefile-Debug.mk:98: warning: overriding commands for target `build/Debug/MinGW-Windows/newmain.o'
nbproject/Makefile-Debug.mk:93: warning: ignoring old commands for target `build/Debug/MinGW-Windows/newmain.o'
mkdir -p build/Debug/MinGW-Windows
rm -f "build/Debug/MinGW-Windows/fourier-transform.o.d"
gcc    -c -g -MMD -MP -MF "build/Debug/MinGW-Windows/fourier-transform.o.d"

Comment: -o build/Debug/MinGW-Windows/fourier-transform.o fourier-transform.c
fourier-transform.c:18:8: error: expected '=', ',', ';', 'asm' or '__attribute__' before 'static'
 public static void main(String[] args) {
        ^~~~~~
make.exe[2]: *** [build/Debug/MinGW-Windows/fourier-transform.o] Error 1
make.exe[2]: Leaving directory `/c/Users/Asus/Documents/NetBeansProjects/CppApplication_1'
make.exe[1]: *** [.build-conf] Error 2
make.exe[1]: Leaving directory

Comment: `/c/Users/Asus/Documents/NetBeansProjects/CppApplication_1'
make.exe": *** [.build-impl] Error 2

BUILD FAILED (exit value 2, total time: 7s)